# Python: using the classification report results from a function in another function

Tags: python

I have written a function that prints the classification report for different segments. Do to the nature of my work, I cannot share my code here. However, I am going to explain what I did.

The function classification_report takes one parameter (t), and calculates the y_pred. Then it uses the following print to print the classification report:

```
print(classification_report(y_test, 'y_pred'))
```

I then define a list of the segments that I want to run this function on:

segments = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

I then use the following for loop on the function to print the classification report for each of the segments:

```
for i in segments:
    classification_report(i)
```

The classification report is a nested dictionary that shows the the precision and recall values.

I now need use these results into another function to make a table based on the results of the precision and recall values. Could you help me how I can do this?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you want to keep the results of `classification_report(i)` for later use, is that correct?

Would something like that work out for you?

```
results = []

for i in segments:
    results.append(classification_report(i))
```

And then you'll be able to access each one with `results[i]`.